# Configuring blue/green gke cluster switch with no downtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-programming, google-kubernetes-engine

When we change from blue to green gke cluster, what is the best way to make sure incomming traffic instantly goes to the new cluster, with no client interruption?

We currently use CloudFlare api to keep the dns updated, but we would prefer not to wait for dns propagation.

We've considered the following:

1. Reserved IP - Would result in a short downtime when reassigning the
   IP.
2. Loadbalancer - Possible.
3. Using another cluster as the Loadbalancer - Possible, but what about B/G switching on that cluster?

Edit:
The reason we want this, is to be more flexible. We can currently create the new cluster, setup everything even with major changes, test it, and finally switch traffic over to the new cluster. The way we do now is using DNS, and setting the old cluster to forward to the new, but I want more control over this switch. We are doing blue/green inside the cluster also.

Comment: You cannot achieve your goals using any off the shelf cloud components. The Internet, DNS, load balancing, client, etc. do not work this way. There is no "instant" switch without some sort of issue or client interruption.

Comment: Why do a whole cluster blue/green switch? Do it for each and every Deployment, so you can update the Service to switch the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you switching between clusters? you can achieve either [blue/green](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/bluegreen-deployments-kubernetes) or [canary](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-canary-deployments-for-mere-mortals-13728ce032fe) deployment within the same cluster with minimal effort and minimal additional resources.

The second you redirect traffic from 1 cluster to another, there will be a delay. Now if you keep both clusters running, there will be no downtime, but there will be a delay in switching over, it won't be instantaneous. You can have the green cluster running and receiving traffic and deploy your blue cluster; once the blue cluster is up, update your DNS to point to the new external IP of your service. The propagation may take a bit of time, but there won't be any downtime.

Comment: I am trying to avoid DNS propagation wait.

Comment: Can you use a single cluster? Is using two different clusters necessary? The alternative is to move the LB up from cluster a to cluster b but that will have some down time

Comment: We could do a single cluster only, but would prefer to solve this problem :)

Yeah, thought about doing it with a static IP in GCP, but would leave some downtime when moving it between the clusters.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive blue/green deployments in GKE using istio with flagger, Flagger is well known for canary and blue/green deployments. You dont need to change DNS between different clusters to achieve blue/green.

What you do is create deployment files (yaml) for kubernetes and define create new file with kind:Canary. K8 will deploy your app after automated load testing and conformance testing.(You can look into this document for furthur info : https://docs.flagger.app/usage/blue-green)